# Indefinite article before 'god'

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

Here's a phrase from a song:

> *There's nothing a god can give to me that I can't give to myself*
>
> *I put my beliefs in the things I believe and a god can take care of himself*

It might seem kind of offensive, please don't pay much attention to the meaning of the phrase, what I'm curious about is solely a grammar stuff.

So,
1. Is it correct to use indefinite article before 'god' at all?
2. If god's already mentioned in the first sentence, would it be better to use 'the' before 'god' in the second one?

Comment: You are under the assumption that there is a single god. The songwriter is clearly talking about an arbitrary god in an array of gods.

Comment: You don’t give any reasons why you think it _wouldn’t_ be grammatically fine to use the word _god_ with an indefinite article.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm under assumption that there is god at all:)

Comment: There may be objections on theological grounds but I see none on grammatical grounds as to why you cannot use the indefinite article with *god*.

Comment: I think It wouldn't be grammatically correct because god is something we all know about, or one of its kind sort of thing, like Earth or Universe or so. Even if we're talking about one arbitrary god in an array of gods.

Comment: @root1916 You mean "You're not sure there *are any gods* at all", or "You're not sure there *is a God* at all".

Comment: And what about 2nd question?

Comment: Dan Bron, you name it :)

Comment: @root1916 What I'm trying to say is there are circumstances where you use the definite article, and circumstances where you use the indefinite article, but in the context you're talking about, you would *not* use the zero article.

Comment: We all know what the _Earth_ is, too, but there's nothing wrong with _an earth_, either. Nor _a universe_, for that matter.

Comment: Dan Bron, thanks. I didn't understand your first comment, actually

Comment: @root1916: It's also not true that there is only one god within any particular belief system.  Many (and I think most religions historically), have numerous gods, ash Hinduism and Shinto do today,

Comment: Even the monotheism of Judaism and Christianity concede *gods* 
From Exodus 12:12: *For I will pass through the land of Egypt this night, and will smite all the firstborn in the land of Egypt, both man and beast; and against all the gods of Egypt I will execute judgment: I am the Lord.* 

John 10:34-5: *Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods? If he called them gods, unto whom the word of God came, and the scripture cannot be broken; Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determiner *[a](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/a#a)* has several uses:

> determiner
>
> 1.0 Used when mentioning someone or something for the first time in a text or conversation:
>
> *a man came out of the room*
>
> 1.1 Used with units of measurement to mean one such unit:
>
> *a hundred*
>
> 1.2 [WITH NEGATIVE] One single; any:
>
> *I simply haven’t a thing to wear*
>
> 1.3 Used when mentioning the name of someone not known to the speaker:
>
> *a Mr Smith telephoned*
>
> 1.4 Someone like (the name specified):
>
> *you’re no better than a Hitler*
>
> 2.0 Used to indicate membership of a class of people or things:
>
> *he is a lawyer*
>
> 3.0 In, to, or for each; per (used when expressing rates or ratios):
>
> *typing 60 words a minute*

In this case, it seems the author simply wants to emphasize 1.2:

> 1.2 [WITH NEGATIVE] One single; any:
>
> *There's nothing [any] god can give to me that I can't give to myself*

Alternately, if its to be interpreted as "one in a class", 2.0:

> Used to indicate membership of a class of people or things:
>
> 2.0 *There's nothing a god [among all of them] can give to me that I can't
> give to myself*

The OP mentioned the first use of *a*, but it is irrelevant if the author's intent was an *indefinite member of a class*, or *any member of a class*.

Comment: Many thanks,I'm not a native speaker, and all this articles grammar is pretty tricky to me. I think different language which has no articles at all so I can't feel their using.  And what about the second part of my question? If songwriter mentioned god in the first sentence, he obviously speaks about the very same god in the second one. Why not definite article is used there?

Comment: In both cases, the author wants to emphasize an *indefinite* god.

Answer (score 2):

There are three phrasings in question

> 1. a god
> 2. the god (or the God)
> 3. God

The indefinite article (*a god*) is relevant to either a **[polytheist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytheism)** belief system (in which there is more than one god), a god independent of religion (as in comparing *a god* from one religion to a god from another, or to an ideal), or else **somebody who is figuratively [godlike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/godlike)** (approaching perfection in a particular skill or knowledge, e.g. the [top 50 users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/35/alltime/english?sort=reputationchange&pagesize=50) on this site are *godlike*).

Using a definite article (*the god*) is relevant to either a **[montheist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotheism)** belief system (in which there is just one god) or else **somebody who is the definitive "best"** (the *most* godlike) at a particular skill or knowledge, e.g. the [#1 user on Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) (at this time of writing, #1 is 758k while #2 is 575k, so this is definitive).  Capitalizing as *the God* refers to monotheism.

*God* without an article should always be capitalized.  It refers to the god ahead of the speaker/writer's (monotheist) religion, particularly for Christianity and Judaism, both of which use "God" as one of their chief preferred proper names for that god.

Atheists tend to use *a god*, though may use *the god* or *God* as appropriate to whatever religion they are referring to.  These lyrics are atheist.  As they do not refer to any religions, they use the general case of *a god*.

When choosing a phrasing, be consistent.  Assuming you're talking about a diety (rather than a person that is godlike), it is very important to always use the same format (within the same context).  The song lyrics in question follow this advice.

Comment: It seems to me that you are imposing a theological side-conversation on a linguistic question. The OP only offers one phrasing: a *god*. The suggestion of *the god* had nothing to do with theology, but with syntax: "If  If god's already mentioned in the first sentence..."

Comment: @ScotM: I had to, to a degree.  When "a god" refers to a deity, it implies there is more than one.  When "the god" refers to a deity, it implies there is only one.  Capitalized "God" without an article refers to a proper name, and only a few monotheist religions use that particular proper name.  I've done my best to be objective and avoid anything dogmatic.  My post was not meant to elicit any theological tangents.

Comment: In terms of theology, I happen to agree, but linguistically: referring to ***the** house* does not even remotely imply that there is **only one** house; it simply **identifies** one house :-) Theology aside, the author of the song did not wish to identify one god.

Comment: Houses are not gods and do not have these subtleties.

Comment: It seems we share that frame of reference theologically, but in language, we must respect the frames of reference that other people use if we wish to communicate. Common ground among mankind: *A god* is generally any **unspecified** god among many; *the god* is an **identified** god among many; *the God* is the unique expression of monotheism.

Answer (score 1):

God (with a capital letter) refers to the creator or supreme being worshipped by adherents of monotheistic religions. A (lower-case) god refers to any of the gods worshipped by adherents of polytheistic religions; Zeus, Krishna, Tara, Ra, Nut, Persephone, Thor, Kwan Yin and so on and so forth.